# Bash capture stderr into variable without redirect

Tags: bash, variables, stderr

Specifically, I'm writing a script to make it easier to compile and run my C++ code. It's easy for it to tell if the compilation succeeded of failed, but I also want to add a state where it "compiled with warnings".

```
$out    # to avoid an "ambiguous redirect"
g++ -Wall -Wextra $1 2> out

if [ $? == 0 ]
then

        # this is supposed to test the length of the output string
        # unless there are errors, $out should be length 0
    if  [ ${#out} == 0 ]
    then
        # print "Successful"
    else
        # print "Completed with Warnings"
    fi

else
    # print "Failed"
fi
```

As it is, the failure case check works fine, but `$out` is always an empty string, though stderr is no longer displaying on the screen, `$out` is never actually set. If possible, I would also like stderr to still go to the screen.

I hope what I've said makes sense. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra $1 2> out
```

This redirects stderr to a file named `out`, not a variable named `$out`.

If you want to run `gcc` and see stdout and stderr on screen as well as save stderr's output, you could use a named pipe (FIFO). It's a bit roundabout, but it'd get the job done.

```
mkfifo stderr.fifo
gcc -Wall -o /dev/null /tmp/warn.c 2> stderr.fifo &
tee stderr.log < stderr.fifo >&2
rm -f stderr.fifo
wait
```

After running these commands, the warnings will be available in `stderr.log`. Taking advantage of the fact that `wait` will return `gcc`'s exit code, you could then do something like:

```
if wait; then
    if [[ -s stderr.log ]]; then
        # print "Completed with Warnings"
    else
        # print "Successful"
    fi
else
    # print "Failed"
fi
```

Annotated:

```
# Created a named pipe. If one process writes to the pipe, another process can
# read from it to see what was written.
mkfifo stderr.fifo

# Run gcc and redirect its stderr to the pipe. Do it in the background so we can
# read from the pipe in the foreground.
gcc -Wall -o /dev/null /tmp/warn.c 2> stderr.fifo &

# Read from the pipe and write its contents both to the screen (stdout) and to
# the named file (stderr.log).
tee stderr.log < stderr.fifo >&2

# Clean up.
rm -f stderr.fifo

# Wait for gcc to finish and retrieve its exit code. `$?` will be gcc's exit code.
wait
```

Answer (score 0):

To capture in a variable and display on the screen, use `tee`:

```
out=$( g++ -Wall -Wextra "$1" 2>&1 >dev/null | tee /dev/stderr )
```

This throws out the standard output of `g++` and redirects standard error to standard output. That output is piped to `tee`, which writes it to the named file (`/dev/stderr`, so that the messages go back to the original standard error) and standard output, which is captured in the variable `out`.

Comment: That captures to `$out`, which was my main problem, though it does not seem to allow `$?` to get the exit status of `g++`, I assume this is because it's running `tee` after compiling. How else can I get this status?

Comment: The `PIPESTATUS` array will hold the exit status of each command in the most recent foreground pipeline, so following this assignment `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` should hold the exit status of `g++`.

Comment: `PIPESTATUS` always seems to hold a single 0, regardless of the exit status of `g++`.

Comment: Ah. The assignment itself is the most recent pipeline. It's a little ugly, but try `out=$( g++... | tee ...; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]})`. This propagates the exit status of `g++` to be the exit status of the assignment. Then you can check `$?` as before.